# Pytorch Forward Pass Changes Each Time?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am learning pytorch and running a toy regression problem. I am baffled by the fact that it appears that each time I run a tensor through a model, the prediction changes. Clearly this is cant be the case but what am I missing?

Pytorch version: `0.4.0`

I am running here without GPU to eliminate that potential issue.

Code:

```python
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.utils.data as utils_data
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch import optim, nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset 
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn.init import xavier_uniform_, xavier_normal_,uniform_
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

cuda=False #set to true uses GPU


#load boston data from scikit
boston = load_boston()
x=boston.data
y=boston.target
y=y.reshape(y.shape[0],1)

#change to tensors
x = torch.from_numpy(x)
y = torch.from_numpy(y)

#create dataset and use data loader
training_samples = utils_data.TensorDataset(x, y)
data_loader = utils_data.DataLoader(training_samples, batch_size=64)

#simple model
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        #all the layers
        self.fc1   = nn.Linear(x.shape[1], 20)
        xavier_uniform_(self.fc1.weight.data) #this is how you can change the weight init
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc2   = nn.Linear(20, 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x=  self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

net=Net()

if cuda:
    net.cuda()

# create a stochastic gradient descent optimizer
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
# create a loss function (mse)
loss = nn.MSELoss(size_average=True)

# run the main training loop
epochs =50
hold_loss=[]

for epoch in range(epochs):
    cum_loss=0.
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(data_loader):
        tr_x, tr_y = data.float(), target.float()
        if cuda:
            tr_x, tr_y = tr_x.cuda(), tr_y.cuda() 

        # Reset gradient
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        fx = net(tr_x)
        output = loss(fx, tr_y) #loss for this batch

        cum_loss += output.item() #accumulate the loss

        # Backward 
        output.backward()

        # Update parameters based on backprop
        optimizer.step()
    hold_loss.append(cum_loss/len(training_samples))  

#training loss
plt.plot(np.array(hold_loss))
```

**This part, if re-ran will return different predictions each time, the actuals dont change so the order of the data is not changing!**

```python
#score the training set
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(data_loader):
        tr_x, tr_y = data.float(), target.float()
        if batch_idx ==0:
           hold_pred=net(tr_x).data.numpy()
           hold_actual=tr_y.data.numpy().reshape(tr_y.data.numpy().shape[0],1)
        else:
            hold_pred =np.row_stack([hold_pred,net(tr_x).data.numpy()])
hold_actual=np.row_stack([hold_actual,tr_y.data.numpy().reshape(tr_y.data.numpy().shape[0],1)])

#view the first few predictions      
print(hold_pred[0:10]) 
print(hold_actual[0:10])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your network has a `Dropout` layer, which has for purpose to randomly sample (with a probability `p=0.5` here) the data it receives during training (`net.train()` set before inference). See the [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#dropout) for more information (usage, purpose).

This layer can be short-circuited during testing (`net.eval()` set before inference).

Comment: Dont know how I missed that (but I never saw it). This needs to be done whenever the prediction is of interest (e.g. end of each epoch to measure loss or of course scoring new data)? Can you toggle back and forth?

Comment: Yes, it can be toggled back and forth ; and the model will stick to the `train` (resp. `eval`) mode until you call the opposite method (`model.eval()` is actually the same as `model.train(mode=False)` which is setting the `model.training` attribute with the `mode` boolean, c.f. [https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L872](pytorch code)).